# Laravel 4 using App::error with App::abort(404)

Tags: php, rest, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to write a RESTful API using Laravel.

My route is so:

```
Route::resource('user', 'UserController');
```

A method is so:

```
public function show($id)
{
    return User::findOrFail($id);
}
```

But if the model instance doesn't exist I get a 500 error, whereas I believe I need a 404 error.

So in start/global.php I have this:

```
App::error(function(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException $exception)
{
    App::abort(404);
});
```

Which gives me a 200 code and the message Error in exception handler.

Am I doing something wrong? I expect no output and a 404 code.

Thanks,

Michael

Comment: Are you sure you're still getting a `200`? Because I just tried on my VM and it gave me a `404`, even though it did display the error stack. How are you checking the error code?

Comment: I can reproduce the behaviour of the OP, running into this string sent with a an HTTP 200 code: `Error in exception handler: in /home/vagrant/CiFR/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Applicatio‌​n.php:910`

Comment: Okey, I managed to reproduce it as well. It happens because you're throwing an error **inside** the error handler. I think the best solution here is to go for @MichaelBearjaws answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just for completeness, the behaviour that the OP mentions (and that can be reproduced), was discussed before on Laravel's Github: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1807. It was decided that it is as designed and will not be changed.

Therefore, returning `Response::make("Not Found", 404);` or `Response::json(null, 404);` for JSON from within the error handler is the only solution at this moment, as already mentioned by [Michael Bearjaws](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25061110/3855399).

Answer (score 3):

You will want to use `Response::make("Not Found", 404);` to actually return a 404 header and display the `"Not Found"` message.

You can also use a view to render your own custom 404 display with the following

`return Response::view('missing', array(), 404);`

You may also add a Missing handler to your application so that it will work with your code

```
App::missing(function($exception) { 
    return Response::view('missing', array(), 404); 
});
```

Comment: It only works the same if you have a 404 handler


App::missing(function($exception)
{
    return Response::view('missing', array(), 404);
});

Comment: I don't have a 404 handler and it just worked. Just like `App::abort(500)` gave 500, and I don't have a handler for it.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I was testing `App::abort(404)` inside the route, not inside the error handler. You were absolutely right. Declaring `App::missing()` doesn't solve it though.

Comment: Hey, I thought about `Response::view()`, but that outputs text. I'm using this as an API and so I just want the 404 status code with no output. In the same way that putting `App::abort()` straight in to the route works.

Comment: Try `Response::make('', 404)`. **Edit:** Because this is an API, @lowerends suggestion to go for `Response::json(null, 404)` seems better.

Answer (score 3):

Change the `debug` config value in `app/config/local/app.php` (if you're on local, as you should) to `false` to assert you're actually getting a 404.

You could also:

- Run a unit test with the phpdoc: `@expectedException Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException`. ***recommended***
- Push your commit to development to see if it's actually working.

Comment: This doesn't really seem to be case, I just got a `404` **with** the error stack trace. Have you tested it? Or is there some detail I'm missing?

Comment: @Raphael_ You're right, I got confused with unit tests breaking on 404s instead of asserting the response code as 404. Fixed my answer.